# converting a string to an int gives a compile error?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

After looking through some of the 'how to convert string to int' posts on SO, I resorted to using;

```
public MyObject(Object parObject)
{
    this.VersionInt = Convert.ToInt32(this.parObject.VersionString);
    // object has a field called 'VersionString' which holds a 
    // string-typed version number (1.0, 2.3, etc.)
}

public int VersionInt{ get; set; }
```

However, I get the compile message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'.
Isn't that exactly what the method is supposed to do and thus makes the compile error obsolete?

My apologies if this is somehow a duplicate to something, but I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem. Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..

Converting it to a double and casting it to an int like this;

```
this.VersionInt = (int)Convert.ToDouble(this.parObject.VersionString);
```

or

```
this.VersionInt = (Int32)Convert.ToDouble(this.parObject.VersionString);
```

gives me the same message.

**EDIT:**
Because everybody is telling me the pseudo-names are more confusing than clarifying, here's the actual code;

```
private EA.Element element;

public Requirement(EA.Element element)
{
    this.element = element;
    this.Status = (int)Convert.ToDouble(this.element.Status);
}

public string Status { get; set; }
```

the `this.element.Status` is a `string`. There's really no doubt there, because the compiler tells me so when I hover it; (`string EA.IDualElement.Status { get; set; }`

**Another Edit:**
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..
Might be because I'm overlooking something obvious..

Might be because at the end of my workday I'm starting to convert Version-types to Status-types.. I am so terribly sorry for taking up your time, I'm going to get myself another coffee

Comment: Try converting to a Double first, then cast to Int32.

Comment: What is the type of the `String` property?

Comment: @Meloviz updated main post

Comment: Side note - `object`, `String`, and `Int` are _terrible_ names for properties.  You're just confusing things more than than helping.

Comment: @DStanley as mentioned in the post; it's a **string-typed** field called String (for clarity purposes) which holds a versionnumber.

Comment: Why is it saying you cannot convert an Int to a String when you're trying to convert a String to an int? Seems to me that your issue might be somewhere else than this block of code.

Comment: Currently it's impossible that you get this error because `Int` is an `int` property. So why should the compiler complain that he can't convert an `int` to a `string`. Are you sure that you show us the correct line? But you are passing `Object` to the method which has no `String´ property, instead you use `this.object` which you haven't shown. Very confusing.

Comment: and I think even the property named Int is a String :D

Comment: What if you put `.ToString()` after `this.parObject.VersionString`? Giving you `this.parObject.VersionString.ToString()`

Comment: "Isn't that exactly what the method is supposed to do and thus makes the compile error obsolete?" -- I'd say so. Can you edit your question to include some real code (not pseudo-code, get rid of the syntax errors, make it something someone else can just copy and paste) that demonstrates the compiler error?

Comment: why not use ``Version`` class with ``Version.TryParse`` as it is version looks like

Comment: @hvd included the real code, noticed that I was writing the converted element.Version (string to int) to this.Status (string) instead of this.Version (int). My most viewed question so far; My most stupid question so far ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get a *cpmpiler*-error? I suppose you get an error when *executing* your code, making this a *runtime*-error. In particular you can´t convert `"1.2"` to an integer, as it is - if anything - a `double`. Thus you have to split it at `.` using `String.Split`:

```
string[] numbers = mthis.parObject.VersionString.Split('.');
this.VersionMajor = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
this.VersionMinor = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);
```

Anyway, why not simply use the [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.version.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)-class which does all this for you out of the box?

```
Version version;
if(Version.TryParse("1.2", out version)) { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing, because actually you can't get the error that you've mentioned with that code. Why should the compiler complain about that he can't convert an int to string when the code that you've shown converts a string to int?

However, since you use versions that aren't integers at all. You should hold a [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) instance or at least multiple `int`-properties like `Major` and `Minor`.

To create a version you can use [`Version.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// note that i've changed Object to MyObject 
public MyObject(MyObject parObject)
{
    Version v;
    if(Version.TryParse(parObject.VersionString, out v))
    {
        this.Version = v;
    }
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid version: " + parObject.VersionString);
}

public Version Version { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the `TryParse` method for this.

```
    var intAsString = "99";
    var intAsInt = 0;
    if(!TryParse(intAsString, out intAsInt))
    {
        //Didn't parse int properly.
    }
```

Comment: I tried using the Tryparse as well, gives me the same error

Comment: You probably ment `Int32.TryParse`, didn´t you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The qualifier is redundant, no? Isn't it int by default?

Comment: There is no class that is used by default. The method is defined in many different classes anyway, for example int `Int32`, in `Double`... So how to distinguish?